# "libesl called unimplement opengl es API"

Tags: android, android-ndk, opengl-es

I tried to make a demo of opengles 2.0 by using android ndk,
Logcat showed the error information "libesl called unimplement opengl es API".
Why?
I'm following OpenGL ES 2.0 Programming Guide's first example.
Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you run it in the emulator or on a proper Android device?  The emulator doesn't support OpenGL at all!

Comment: I changed to OpenGLES1.1, now it's working.I think android may not support OpenGLES2.0 very well.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check this answer:

[Android: GLES20: Called unimplemented OpenGL ES API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926316/android-gles20-called-unimplemented-opengl-es-api)

In a nutshell, the application needs to be told to use OpenGLES 2.0.

You could start with the hello-gl2 sample in the NDK.  The Java-side setup looks a bit complicated but does the job.