# Android: GLES20: Called unimplemented OpenGL ES API

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am getting a "Called unimplemented OpenGL ES API" error, when trying the GLES20 Sample, provided by developer.android.com. I modified the sample, though. 
The reason was because 
I got an IllegalArgumentException in GLSurfaceView.BaseConfigChooser.chooseconfig, so i replaced 
`mGLSurfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion( 2 );`

The new OnCreateMethod:

```
protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
{
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    mGLSurfaceView = new GLSurfaceView( this );

    mGLSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser( new EGLConfigChooser()
    {
        @Override
        public EGLConfig chooseConfig( EGL10 egl, EGLDisplay display )
        {
            EGLConfig[] configs = new EGLConfig[1];
            int[] num_config = new int[1];

            boolean check = false;

            int[] configSpec = { EGL10.EGL_DEPTH_SIZE, 16, EGL10.EGL_NONE };

            check = egl.eglInitialize( display, new int[] { 2, 0 } );

            if ( !check )
                return null;
            check = false;

            check = egl.eglChooseConfig( display, configSpec, configs, 1, num_config );
            if ( !check )
                return null;

            return configs[0];
        }
    } );

    mGLSurfaceView.setEGLContextFactory( new EGLContextFactory()
    {
        @Override
        public void destroyContext( EGL10 egl, EGLDisplay display, EGLContext context )
        {
            egl.eglDestroyContext( display, context );
        }

        @Override
        public EGLContext createContext( EGL10 egl, EGLDisplay display, EGLConfig eglConfig )
        {
            int[] attrib_list = new int[]{EGL10.EGL_VERSION, 2, EGL10.EGL_NONE};

            EGLContext context = egl.eglCreateContext( display, eglConfig, EGL10.EGL_NO_CONTEXT, attrib_list  );
            return context;
        }
    });

    mGLSurfaceView.setRenderer( new GLES20TriangleRenderer( this ) );

    setContentView( mGLSurfaceView );
}
```

The "Called unimplemented OpenGL ES API" error occurs for example at 
`GLES20.glCreateShader;` or `GLES20.glShaderSource`.

I thought, maybe to check the version, so I called 
`gl.glGetString( GLES20.GL_VERSION );` in 
`public void onSurfaceCreated( GL10 gl, EGLConfig config )`.
glGetString returned "OpenGL ES-CM 1.0". OnSurfaceCreated is called after choosing the config and creating the context, so I really do not understand, why glGetString returns "OpenGL ES-CM 1.0".

I am using Android 2.2 API and tried the sample on a Android 2.2 Virtual device and on a HTC Wildfire, with Android 2.2.1.

I appreciate any help

Comment: I'm not too experienced with GL ES 1.1/2.0 but it's better to very much aware emulator does not implement them very well AFAIK. And you can end up with code that works on device but not on emulator.

Answer (score 2):

See this post -
[triangle opengl in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945321/triangle-opengl-in-android)

As mentioned there, the emulators do not support GL2, but as that post mentions, it worked for me on an actual device.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error, but a statement. It simply tells you that your target doesn't support OpenGL ES version 2.0.

Comment: Ok, that sounds logically. The HTC Wildfire only has OpenGL ES 1.0 support. So I can assume, that virtual devices do not support OpenGL ES 2.0. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you are using the GL10 instance we are getting as a parameter in onSurfaceCreated(), onSurfaceChanged() and onDrawFrame() in your Renderer implementation. Since you intend to use OpenGL ES 2.0, we can and probably not use the instance and use an alternative instead. There are alternatives! This is the reason we see those parameters names and unused or similar in codes across the net!