# Android OpenGL ES 2.0 Framebuffers - Called unimplemented OpenGL ES API

Tags: android, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0

I ran my [OpenGL ES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_ES) 2.0 sample app (which runs on fine on iOS devices) on [HTC Desire HD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTC_Desire_HD) (2.3.3), and I'm getting tons of the following messages in LogCat.

> Called unimplemented OpenGL ES API

The error is even generated when I use `glBindFramebuffer`. I used `glBindFramebufferOES` in OpenGL ES 1.0, and it worked fine. As far as I know Framebuffers are included as a non-extension in OpenGL ES 2.0.

Why am I getting this error? It is stated that my device has an OpenGL ES 2.0 driver. Is this a device specific bug?

Comment: Fixed this issue. I wasn't using an OpenGL ES 2.0 context.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. How can I use an OpenGL ES 2.0 context? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this answer helped:

[Android: GLES20: Called unimplemented OpenGL ES API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926316/android-gles20-called-unimplemented-opengl-es-api)

Basically, the AndroidManifest.xml and Java wrapping code both have to indicate that OpenGLES 2.0 is desired.

Answer (score 0):

Call setEGLContextClientVersion(2); on your GLSurfaceView class in your activity, and this should work.