# What version of OpenGL does HTC Wildfire support?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk

I'm testing my app on HTC Wildfire running Android 2.2.1. I suppose it should support atleast OpenGL 1.1 but in fact when I'm calling

```
glGetString(GL_VERSION);
```

I'm getting this:

> OpenGL ES-CM 1.0

Is there any way to create OpenGL 1.1 context and not 1.0 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, HTC Wildfire doesn't have GPU.

- http://developer.qualcomm.com/device/htc-wildfire

  > CPU:Qualcomm MSM 7225
  >
  > Graphical Processor Unit (GPU): No GPU
- [GL info for HTC Wildfire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093594/opengl-extensions-available-on-different-android-devices/6648982#6648982)

  > OpenGL Version - OpenGL ES-CM 1.0
  >
  > OpenGL Vendor - Android
  >
  > OpenGL Renderer - Android PixelFlinger 1.3

It is the software implementation of OpenGL ES 1.0 from Google Android. It is not OpenGL ES 1.1 implementation even though it supports OpenGL ES 1.1 API and extensions partially.

Comment: It's not quite clear why does HTC doesn't support OpenGL 1.1 cause for example all pre-iPhone 3Gs devices also have no GPU but they fully support 1.1.

Comment: Nope, the original iPhone has GPU (PowerVR MBX - [PowerVR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerVR)).

Answer (score 1):

Would this help?
[Android: GLES20: Called unimplemented OpenGL ES API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926316/android-gles20-called-unimplemented-opengl-es-api)

I'm not sure if you already registered the OpenGL in your AndroidManifest.xml by doing:

```
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"></uses-feature>
    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="8" android:minSdkVersion="8"></uses-sdk>
```

Hope this helps!