# Google Maps API v2 only supports devices with OpenGL ES 2.0 and above

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I got this error in Logcat:

> 06-10 00:41:15.948: E/Google Maps Android API(1085): Google Maps
>   Android API v2 only supports devices with OpenGL ES 2.0 and above

Last time I ran the app was before about 10 days and didn't have such a problem. The map was plotting correct and didn't have any errors.

Now I run it again and I get this error. Haven't change a single line of my code.

Was there any update that caused the problem? Like an API update or on Google Play Services?

Maps app on my device works. I use HTC Wildfire

Comment: Well, since the HTC Wildfire reportedly doesn't have OpenGL ES 2.0, I am surprised the app ever worked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020324/what-version-of-opengl-does-htc-wildfire-support

Comment: @CommonsWare that's what I don't understand! Something must have changed since.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't worry about what changed. Use some of the code snippets on the linked-to question/answers to confirm the OpenGL ES version on your Wildfire. If it indeed it is less than OpenGL ES 2.0, your app isn't *supposed* to run on it, in which case you will either need to get a newer device or switch to some other mapping library (e.g., OpenStreetMap) that might not have this particular hardware requirement.

Comment: Per the [June 2, 2013 Google Dashboard](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#OpenGL) - Open GL 2.0 is supported by 99.8% of devices that visited the Play Store in the last 14 days. I would suggest getting an Open GL 2.0 compatible device and test your application on it.

Comment: Seems like you are not alone. See comment 22: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4699#c22