# Android Native NDK OpenGL ES: unimplemented API

Tags: c++, opengl-es, android-ndk, setup-deployment, native-code

I am working to implement an OpenGL ES 2.0 fully in C++ for Android.

Currently our program runs without JNI or any java class in the project, using instead only NativeActivity.

Focusing on the application rendering part itself, we got a simple method:

```
renderWorld()
{   GLfloat vVertices[] = {  0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f,
                            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
                             0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f };
    glClear ( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    glVertexAttribPointer ( 0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vVertices );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray ( 0 );

    glDrawArrays (GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3 );
}
```

In Android.mk was included:

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -landroid -llog -lEGL -lGLESv1_CM -lOpenSLES -lGLESv2
```

And in AndroidManifest.xml is informed:

```
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"></uses-feature>
```

So, the program debugs and compiles with no problem. When set to run, comes the message:

```
    error  libEGL   called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
```

The Forum gives a suggestion workable for java - [Android: GLES20: Called unimplemented OpenGL ES API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926316/android-gles20-called-unimplemented-opengl-es-api) , including to the code the command setEGLContextClientVersion:

```
    GLSurfaceView surfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
    surfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
```

However, the setEGLContextClientVersion is kind of a wrapper method meant for java.

The setEGLContextClientVersion does not belong to OpenGL ES native, and can not be applicable for native C++ OGLES development.

Therefore, I used instead:

```
const EGLint attribList[] = {EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2,EGL_NONE};
mContext = eglCreateContext(mDisplay, lConfig, EGL_NO_CONTEXT,attribList);
```

But the error has not gone away yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you using real device (which?), or you are on emulator (which doesn't support OGL ES2)? Also I'm not sure if linking GLESv1_CM and GLESv2 in same app is a good idea. If you want OpenGL ES 2.0, then link only to GLESv2.

How did you initalized EGL context? Did you used EGL attribute EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT like:

```
EGLint aEGLAttributes[] =
{
    EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT, // <--- OpenGL ES 2.0
    ...
    EGL_NONE
};
...
eglChooseConfig(m_EGLDisplay, aEGLAttributes, aEGLConfigs, 1,
            &cEGLConfigs)
...
```

Comment: Thanks man! I followed your suggestion. It solved the problem.