# GLView with GLES20 crash

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

In my app i have this error:

LogCat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(23121): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(23121): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gles_jni.EGLImpl cannot be cast to javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGL11
E/AndroidRuntime(23121):    at it.hidden.math.GLView.initGL(GLView.java:103)
E/AndroidRuntime(23121):    at it.hidden.math.GLView.surfaceChanged(GLView.java:168)
E/AndroidRuntime(23121):    at it.hidden.math.Graph3dView.surfaceChanged(Graph3dView.java:1)
E/AndroidRuntime(23121):    at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:580)
E/AndroidRuntime(23121):    at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:86)
E/AndroidRuntime(23121):    at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:174)
E/AndroidRuntime(23121):    at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:680)
E/AndroidRuntime(23121):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1842)
E/AndroidRuntime(23121):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
E/AndroidRuntime(23121):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
E/AndroidRuntime(23121):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
E/AndroidRuntime(23121):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
E/AndroidRuntime(23121):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
E/AndroidRuntime(23121):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
E/AndroidRuntime(23121):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
E/AndroidRuntime(23121):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(23121):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(23121):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
E/AndroidRuntime(23121):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(23121):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(23121):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
E/AndroidRuntime(23121):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
E/AndroidRuntime(23121):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

this is the code in GLView class:

```
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGL10;
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGL11;
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLContext;
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLDisplay;
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLSurface;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL11;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;

abstract class GLView extends GLSurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private boolean hasSurface;
private boolean paused;
private EGL11 egl;
private EGLDisplay display;
private EGLConfig config;    
private EGLSurface surface;
private EGLContext eglContext;
private GLES20 gl;
protected int width, height;
private boolean mIsLooping;

abstract void onDrawFrame(GLES20 gl2);
abstract void onSurfaceCreated(GLES20 gl2, int width, int height);

public String captureScreenshot() {
    Bitmap bitmap = getRawPixels(gl, width, height);
    Util.bitmapBGRtoRGB(bitmap, width, height);
    return Util.saveBitmap(bitmap, Grapher.SCREENSHOT_DIR, "calculator");
}

private static Bitmap getRawPixels(GLES20 gl2, int width, int height) {
    int size = width * height;
    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(size * 4);
    buf.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    gl2.glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buf);
    int data[] = new int[size];
    buf.asIntBuffer().get(data);
    buf = null;
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    bitmap.setPixels(data, size-width, -width, 0, 0, width, height);
    return bitmap;
}

private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        glDraw();

    }
};

public GLView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
    init();
}


public GLView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setEGLContextClientVersion(2);

    init();
}

private void init() {
    SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
    holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_GPU);
    setEGLContextClientVersion(2);

    holder.addCallback(this);
}

public void onResume() {
    Calculator.log("onResume " + this);
    paused = false;
    if (hasSurface) {
        initGL();
    }
}

public void onPause() {
    Calculator.log("onPause " + this);
    deinitGL();
}

private void initGL() {
    egl = (EGL11) EGLContext.getEGL();
    display = egl.eglGetDisplay(EGL10.EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);       
    int[] ver = new int[2];
    egl.eglInitialize(display, ver);

    int[] configSpec = {EGL10.EGL_NONE};
    EGLConfig[] configOut = new EGLConfig[1];
    int[] nConfig = new int[1];
    egl.eglChooseConfig(display, configSpec, configOut, 1, nConfig);

    config = configOut[0];

    eglContext = egl.eglCreateContext(display, config, EGL10.EGL_NO_CONTEXT, null);
    surface = egl.eglCreateWindowSurface(display, config, getHolder(), null);
    egl.eglMakeCurrent(display, surface, surface, eglContext);
    gl = (GLES20) eglContext.getGL();
    onSurfaceCreated(gl, width, height);
    requestDraw();
}


private void deinitGL() {
    paused = true;
    if (display != null) {
        egl.eglMakeCurrent(display, EGL10.EGL_NO_SURFACE, EGL10.EGL_NO_SURFACE, EGL10.EGL_NO_CONTEXT);
        egl.eglDestroySurface(display, surface);
        egl.eglDestroyContext(display, eglContext);
        egl.eglTerminate(display);

        egl = null;
        config = null;
        eglContext = null;
        surface = null;
        display = null;
        gl = null;
    }
}

protected void glDraw() {
    if (hasSurface && !paused) {
        onDrawFrame(gl);
        if (!egl.eglSwapBuffers(display, surface)) {
            Calculator.log("swapBuffers error " + egl.eglGetError());
        }
        if (egl.eglGetError() == EGL11.EGL_CONTEXT_LOST) {
            Calculator.log("egl context lost " + this);
            paused = true;
        }
        if (mIsLooping) {
            requestDraw();
        }
    }
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Calculator.log("surfaceCreated " + this);
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    Calculator.log("surfaceChanged " + format + ' ' + this);
    this.width  = width;
    this.height = height;
    boolean doInit = !hasSurface && !paused;
    hasSurface = true;
    if (doInit) {
        initGL();
    }
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Calculator.log("surfaceDestroyed " + this);
    hasSurface = false;
    deinitGL();
}

public void startLooping() {
    if (!mIsLooping) {
        Calculator.log("start looping");
        mIsLooping = true;
        glDraw();
    }
}

public void stopLooping() {
    if (mIsLooping) {
        Calculator.log("stop looping");
        mIsLooping = false;
    }
}

public boolean isLooping() {
    return mIsLooping;
}

public void requestDraw() {
    handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
}
}
```

I'm having all these problems from when in manifest I've included this instruction:

Android: hardwareAccelerated = "true"

I posted another question before, because the app it gave me the following error:

Called unimplemented OpenGL ES API

I then changed GLView.class trying to use GLES20 but I find myself with the logcat posted in this question

Old question:
[Called unimplemented OpenGL ES API Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20474127/called-unimplemented-opengl-es-api-android?noredirect=1#comment30596995_20474127)

Comment: GL10 is for v1.0 and GL11 is for v1.1, I think. If you are going to use 2.0, include the proper packages. Some references are possibly declared in each version with the same name and dalvik may resolve any of them (including not proper ones). This is at first sight, what I see.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you understand the basics of implementing OpenGL in android.

You don't have to do anything with the `SurfaceHolder`. You only need to call the `setRenderer()` method of the GLSurfaceView, and pass a class that implements Renderer interface. Check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html) link for more information. Also you should check out the android samples.

If you want to use GLES20, then you are **never** going to have an GLES20 class instance, you are using static calls to manipulate the surface. [You can find those calls in the GLES20 class.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLES20.html) Also make sure to only call these methods while you are in one of the Renderer class callback methods.

Also make sure you are using the classes from android.opengl.* package.